# MongoDb Atlas - Filter by Date without ISODate returns zero results

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-atlas, isodate

How to force MongoDb Atlas to return results WITHOUT using ISODate?

There are screenshots of my problem:

With ISODate it returns results:
[image]

But WITHOUT ISDODate it returns zero results:
[image]

I don't want to use ISODate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#-datetostring--aggregation-) to do so, this requires an aggregation pipeline like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      createdAt: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$createdAt",
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HODX10x4UP6)

You can also use the `format` and `timezone` parameters for `$dateToString` to change the output to match the structure you require.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works.

**Never** store date/time values as strings, it's a design flaw. Use always proper `Date` object (`ISODate()` is just an alias for `new Date()`). So, you are doing it right!

Of course, when you store `Date` values the you have to compare with a `Date` value - not strings.

The result shown as `2021-03-321T14:22:16.595+00:00` is just the way how your client application displays date values. Typically you can change it in your client preferences.